# how can i import js file on my jsp file in springboot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, jsp

i just load css and js on my jsp

but it just load css not js

this is my code

jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<!-- Static content -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/app.js"></script>

<title>Spring Boot</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Spring Boot - MVC web application example</h1>
  <hr>

  <div class="form">
    <form action="hello" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Enter Your name</td>
          <td><input id="name" name="name"></td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

tree

```
java
-*.java

resources
-css
--*.css
-js
--*.js

webapp
-WEB-INF
--view
---*.jsp
```

[image]

Comment: css can't load too!

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash that's not work i found other way